# Where are Plesk mail queues? Postfix queue? Spamassassin queue? Kaserpy queue?

Tags: email, postfix

I have problems with incoming email on my Plesk server, so I was looking for the email queues.

Emails are stored in `/var/qmail`. However, there is no `/var/qmail/queue`. I think it’s using the Postfix queues in `/var/spool/postfix`. But those are empty.

Does anyone know where the SpamAssassin SPF and Kaspersky queues are located?

Postfix is used for email delivery.

Comment: @Manuel: The very presence of Plesk makes this question [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Your knowledge level doesn't play a role in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never described your problem? Is your mail not being delivered to a local inbox?

But as to where these scanners hold their queues... I would assume: in Memory.

Postfix takes in the Mail, and queues messages (depending on your configuration).

It then processes it through each of the programs you have mentioned. for example: SpamAssassin will be called while processing the Queue, and will return whether or not the email should be accepted for delivery.

Regardless, I would recommend that you increase the Logging Level of postfix, and keep an eye on your Mail Log. If you notice anything related to mail delivery, or a hint to why it might not being delivered.. use that to help you, or post what is says here.

Comment: my server is crashed and I'd like to backup the emails.

Comment: the mails in the queue? or do you want to back up each users inbox?

Comment: if you are just trying to backup each users inbox; check your configuration files to see where postfix is storing each users inbox. this might be under /var/ somewhere, but it might also be in their home directory (depending on configuration). you should be able to copy their Maildir to preserve for backup